# Is there an IDE independent way to configure execution and debug environments with CMake?

Tags: cmake

With the current CMake version 3.28, I can define [`cmake-presets`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.28/manual/cmake-presets.7.html) for configuration, build, package and tests.

I can define environment variables for each of these steps. Especially for tests the environment variable `Path` to find external DLLs when executing. But also other environment variables like `QT_WIN_DEBUG_CONSOLE` might be required.

What I am missing is a way to do this for normal execution or debugging of applications. Each IDE provides its own way, but a common standard way that all IDEs can adapt to would of course be better.

I am primarily interested in environment variables, but of course the working directory and command line arguments would also be useful in this context.

Is there a way to define such a standard environment for executing and debugging applications with CMake?